# Custom cache dependencies in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Anyone ever got custom cache dependencies working with NHibernate second level query cache (i.e. using overrides of the .NET CacheDependency)?

I'm pretty sure it is not possible out-of-the-box, but I know that NHibernate is pretty hackable.

The cache region system doesn't really support the flexibility you have when you can instantiate a cache dependency as you put data into the cache.

Here's what the code might look like:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>("foo")
   .SetCacheable()
   .Add(Restriction.Eq("foo.Name", fooName))
   .AddCacheDependency(new MyCustomCacheDependency(fooName))
   .List<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache dependencies are handled by the cache providers, not the core.

There are some examples of DB-based expiration in the [documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2) for the SysCache2 provider.

Comment: Yeah, but like I said, SysCache2 doesn't support the type of custom cache dependencies one might be interested in.

Comment: You can always plug in your own provider... extend the existing ones... etc.